# Fastest way to create column in pandas based on multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm currently using this function:

```
def age_groupf(row):
    if row['Age'] <= 19:
        val = '15-19'
    elif row['Age'] <= 24:
        val = '20-24'
    elif row['Age'] <= 29:
        val = '25-29'
    elif row['Age'] <= 34:
        val = '30-34'
    elif row['Age'] <= 39:
        val = '35-39'
    elif row['Age'] <= 44:
        val = '40-44'
    elif row['Age'] <= 49:
        val = '45-49'
    elif row['Age'] <= 54:
        val = '50-54'
    elif row['Age'] <= 59:
        val = '55-59'
    else:
        val = '60 and more'
    return val
```

to generate AGE-GROUP fields by calling:

```
DF['AGE-GROUP'] = DF.apply(age_groupf, axis=1)
```

seems like it's working but it's slow. I have multiple 100MB TXT files and I need this to be faster.

Comment: check `pd.cut` or `np.select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) with defined `bins` and `labels`.

For example:

```
bins = [15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, np.inf]
labels = [f'{x}-{y-1}' if y!=np.inf else f'{x} and more' for x, y in zip(bins[::], bins[1::])]

pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```